# Mongodb in linux server

Tags: linux, node.js, mongodb

Using SSH I installed Mongodb in linux server by the following steps.

1. Download and extract latest Mongodb release to the `/bin` folder in serer
2. Edit the `.bash_profile` and add

   PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.0/bin

   ```
   export PATH
   ```
3. Directory created for db saving using `mkdir -p /data/db`
4. Run `mongod --dbpath /data/db`
5. Run `mongo`

After running mongo command, it shows the error like this :

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0
connecting to: test
2014-04-24T10:07:58.831+0530 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-04-24T10:07:58.832+0530 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

How it can solve?

Comment: Could you check what "mongod --dbpath /data/db" prints after starting? It should say some like "Accepting connections from...." after it starts. My guess is mongod start itself is failing.

Comment: Yes. run this command and it shows ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath. So i run mongod --dbpath /home/ecareago/data/db/ - it doesn't shows any error. After this i run mongo and shows the connection refused error.

Comment: check the mongodb log. I would guess it's because of permissions. Why don't you use 10-gen source anyway?

Comment: @user3201764 So, after you create a directory or give an existing directory it works right?

Comment: @yaoxing Where i can check the log? Its the first time i'm trying to install mongodb in linux server.

Comment: @LalitAgarwal Yes. I created a directory /data and create /db inside that.

Comment: If you didn't specify a file for it, it's the output after running mongod command. What does the output say?

Comment: When i run mongod - output is something like this
*********************************************************************
 ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
*********************************************************************
, terminating

Comment: Then follow the instructions and create a directory or give some other directory. If mongod is running successfully, it should be printing log continuously.

Comment: Where i can check the logs?

Comment: the output is the log. if you specify --logpath then it goes to a log file. Otherwise it's in the shell.

Comment: Ok and how it can solve?

Answer (score 15):

First of all, make sure your dbpath exists.

```
mkdir -p ~/data/db
```

Then start mongod with:

```
mongod --dbpath ~/data/db
```

Finally:

```
mongo
```

**EDIT**: I saw some people vote this answer up. To make it clear, this solution is for you to start mongod with command line. Most of the time if you installed MongoDB package from source, you can just start the daemon with:

```
sudo systemctl start mongodb # Arch linux
sudo service mongod start # CentOS/Redhat
```

Configuration file can be found in:

```
vim /etc/mongod.conf
```

And if you want daemon to be auto started from boot,

```
sudo systemctl enable mongodb # Arch Linux
sudo chkconfig mongod on # CentOS/Redhat
```

Comment: when i run this sudo mkdir -p /data/db - it output "username" is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: Do you have root permission? if not, don't try to mkdir in root directory. Just do that in your own home directory. I'll update my answer to show you how

Comment: I run the new code and still exist the same connection refused error. 
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0
connecting to: test
2014-04-24T12:38:31.950+0530 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-04-24T12:38:31.951+0530 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed

Comment: what's the output this time?

Comment: After run mongo the output is 
----------"
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0 connecting to: test 2014-04-24T12:38:31.950+0530 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused 2014-04-24T12:38:31.951+0530 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146 exception: connect failed

Comment: mongod --dbpath ~/data/db--------
2014-04-24T13:04:37.550+0530 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6844 port=27017 dbpath=/home/ecareago/data/db 64-bit host=ecareagorahost.ecareagora.com
2014-04-24T13:04:37.550+0530 [initandlisten] 
2014-04-24T13:04:37.550+0530 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running in OpenVZ which can cause issues on versions of RHEL older than RHEL6.-------- something like

Comment: How about the last few lines?

Comment: [initandlisten] dbexit: 
[initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
[initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
[initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
[initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
[initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
[initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
[initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
[initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
[initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
[initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now

Comment: a little bit earlier. try finding out what the error is.

Comment: Then why is it shutting down...you killed the process?

Comment: Thank you for you help, but there are a little typo for archlinux command its : sudo systemctl start mongodb # start must be before the service name
And we can also add sudo systemctl enable mongodb if we want the service start at every boot

Answer (score 1):

I was having this error message after a clean install of mongodb.

What worked for me was removing the lock file and starting mongodb again.

Maybe see if that helps?

Source:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MongoDB

Comment: Wonder why someone down-voted that as it helper fix the exact problem for me, and obviously works for others using Arch as it's in their WIKI.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue after copying all mongodb files form one server to another in

> /var/lib/mongodb/

directory. Solution in my case was to change permission group to all files and folders in

> /var/lib/mongodb/

to

> mongodb:nogroup