# Mongodb refusing connection with error 111, found weird fix

Tags: mongodb

I had a fresh install of mongodb and it worked fine but after restarting my computer it stopped working, so i decided to look for answers and found this one

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260119/mongodb-in-linux-server)

Which is the exact problem that i am having and doing

```
mkdir -p ~/data/db    
mongod --dbpath ~/data/db
```

started running mongodb but i have to open another terminal to get mongodb shell running; I'm still new to mongodb so any tips on why this is happening will be great. Also any way to fix this so that I can run mongo command without having to type in the second command

Comment: You can put that command in a .sh file in /etc/init.d/ folder. your command will be automatically executed on start up. Make sure the file has permissions using chmod +x filename.sh. Thanks

Comment: Check the permissions on your db files in their previous location which is most likely `/data/db`

Comment: thanks, I'll do the mentioned things