# Mongo daemon doesn't run by service mongod start

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04

Recently I installed mongodb package by reading this page (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). 
I use docker and ubuntu 14.04 image to deploy my server.

The problems start by first running the **mongod** service:

```
# service mongod start
```

I got the following:

```
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mongod restart

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) and then start(8) utilities,
e.g. stop mongod ; start mongod. The restart(8) utility is also available.
```

I've tried this:

```
# start mongod
```

But got no output.

Next I wanted to check the log, but there is no log!

```
ls /var/log/mongodb -a #empty
```

Ok, next I tried to start **mongo** shell:

```
# mongo
2014-08-12T17:42:44.431+0000 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-08-12T17:42:44.432+0000 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

Ok, after googling I checked (applaied) all answers from [Mongodb in linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260119/mongodb-in-linux-server) and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MongoDB (section **Troubleshooting**), but still get nothing.

The **mongo** shell works only when I run **mongod** directly in background:

```
mongod --verbose &

[DataFileSync] BackgroundJob starting: DataFileSync
shardKeyTest passed
isInRangeTest passed
shardObjTest passed
[initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=451 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=a9d816faea4c
[initandlisten] db version v2.6.4
[initandlisten] git version: 3a830be0eb92d772aa855ebb711ac91d658ee910
[initandlisten] build info: Linux build7.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
[initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
[initandlisten] options: { systemLog: { verbosity: 1 } }
[initandlisten] flushing directory /data/db
[initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
[initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
[initandlisten] flushing directory /data/db/journal
[initandlisten] flushing directory /data/db/journal
[initandlisten] opening db:  local
[initandlisten] enter repairDatabases (to check pdfile version #)
[initandlisten]     local
[initandlisten] done repairDatabases
[initandlisten] opening db:  admin
[initandlisten] query admin.system.roles planSummary: EOF ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) W:119 r:106 nreturned:0 reslen:20 0ms
[ClientCursorMonitor] BackgroundJob starting: ClientCursorMonitor
[PeriodicTaskRunner] BackgroundJob starting: PeriodicTaskRunner
[TTLMonitor] BackgroundJob starting: TTLMonitor
[initandlisten] fd limit hard:1048576 soft:524288 max conn: 419430
[IndexRebuilder] BackgroundJob starting: IndexRebuilder
[IndexRebuilder] opening db:  local
[initandlisten] create collection local.startup_log { size: 10485760, capped: true }
[initandlisten] command local.$cmd command: create { create: "startup_log", size: 10485760, capped: true } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  reslen:75 0ms
[initandlisten] insert local.startup_log ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  0ms
[initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
[IndexRebuilder] checking complete2014-08-12T17:48:29.837+0000 [DataFileSync] BackgroundJob starting: DataFileSync
```

Now I have the following:

```
/var/lib/mongodb (mongodb:mongodb) empty
/var/log/mongodb (mongodb:nogroup) empty
/data/db (mongo:nogroup) #useless

# mongod.conf
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
logappend=true
port = 27017
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
...
```

What's going on here? I'm absolutely confused (

Comment: a. have you checked to see if your install did in fact install anything under /etc/init.d/? b. if you start mongod in the background without telling it to look at your conf file, it will use default directories, not the ones you've specified. to manually start try this; mongod --config /your/path/to/mongod.conf

Comment: a. /etc/init.d/mongod -> /lib/init/upstart-job

Comment: I came to the conclusion that it is better to start mongod manually like you noticed: `mongod --config /your/path/to/mongod.conf`. Everything works ok (for the time being..) Is it right to do so?

Comment: that really depends on whether you want to manage it as a service or not. we have it running as a service so that it can be easily identified. however if you're the person managing it and you know how to look for it and ensure that it's running it shouldn't be a problem. that said, so it links to a library file, have you looked in the file to see if it seems like a valid init file?

Comment: please, could you give me detailed command how to check a validation of init file?

Comment: just open up the init file by using a vim editor or the cat command from a shell. for example if i wanted to see my init file it is not a link so i'd do: `cat /etc/init.d/mongod` or `vim /etc/init.d/mongod`. you can google an init file to see if it in any way resembles a generic init to see if it makes sense

Comment: this is a sample of what an init script should look like. see if you can find the file that /etc/init.d/mongod points to looks anything like this: https://gist.github.com/naholyr/4275302 (note this is for a different program but the syntax should be similar)

Comment: `/etc/init.d/mongod` is not a file - it is just link to `/lib/init/upstart-job`. Do I need to place the content of this file for you?

Comment: no. you should look at the content of the file that it points to to see if it looks anything similar to the init sample i linked to. if it does and the service isn't working i would try re-installing. or just not use the service

Comment: To be honest I don't understand what to do.. I don't have deep linux knowledges( I need explicit actions because I noob :)

Comment: include output of `dpkg -L mongodb-org` and `dpkg -L mongodb-org-server`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker containers typically does not have a full init system and interaction with upstart will not work inside a docker container. (In theory it is possible, but it defeats the purposes of having light weight stack)

What this implies is that you start a docker container, it would run a single command "/usr/bin/mongod"

Example of running mongodb inside a docker container: 
https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/mongo/

Also since you are running installation commands using an interactive docker container, your shell interpreter is the single command as far as docker is considered.  Once in interactive session,  you can run mongod in background (As you did) and start mongo client session.

Another way would be to run these instructions as part of [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/). You can refer to [mongodb example](https://docs.docker.com/examples/mongodb/).

You might also want to consider some of the official mongo db images already published in docker hub:

https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mongo/

Comment: Docker links are invalid

Comment: @mujaffars Thanks for pointing that out.  I have updated the links. Looks like the  the examples were moved.

Comment: Again links got down @mujaffars.