# Using service start/stop with Docker

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I have a running docker container and I would like to execute :

```
service mongod status/start/stop ..etc
```

I would like to konw why I am having this output:

```
sudo docker exec 29c7bf21111e bash -c "service mongod status"

Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mongod status

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the status(8) utility, e.g. status mongod
```

Update:

This is the output of the command without bash -c:

```
$ sudo docker exec 29c7bf271d7e service mongod status
[sudo] password for -: 
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mongod status

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the status(8) utility, e.g. status mongod
```

And when I run another service:

```
sudo docker exec 29c7bf271d7e service cron status
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service cron status

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the status(8) utility, e.g. status cron
```

networking works as it displays the **Usage**:

```
sudo docker exec 29c7bf271d7e service networking status
Usage: /etc/init.d/networking {start|stop|reload|restart|force-reload}
```

Reload networking service:

```
sudo docker exec 29c7bf271d7e service networking reload
 * Reloading network interfaces configuration...
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: What happens when you just drop into bash and run the command yourself? Do you get the same error? It could be that the mongodb image you're running is not properly setup.

Comment: @tayfun Please see the update on the message I posted.

Comment: No by dropping into bash yourself, I meant do `docker exec 29c bash` and then running the service commands yourself. You'll probably have a better view that way.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111212/docker-container-mongod-error-when-starting-via-ssh