# mongodb won't start from nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The problem: web page works only if i manually start the mongodb. Otherwise i get error "Error failed to connect 127.0.0.1:27017". However, I believe i do create server, maybe i am missing some step.

Also, feel free to point out better ways of doing things, or if something is outdated...

The code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    cons = require('consolidate'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server;

app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

var mongoclient = new MongoClient(new Server("127.0.0.1", 27017));
var db = mongoclient.db('course');

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    // Find one document in our collection
    db.collection('hello_combined').findOne({}, function(err, doc) {

        if(err) throw err;

        res.render('hello', doc);
    });
});

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.send('Page Not Found', 404);
});

mongoclient.open(function(err, mongoclient) {

    if(err) throw err;

    app.listen(8080);
    console.log('Express server started on port 8080');
});
```

Comment: do you have the mongo deamon running?. Start the mongo client in terminal and check you could connect to server via the client.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't "*start from Node.js*." Node.js is a client that can connect to a running MongoDB server. The `Server` type is just what the library uses to track the details of a server that it can connect to. You will have to manage `mongod` separately.

Comment: Agree, it's standalone, not started from nodejs. If you have problem starting mongodb, read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260119/mongodb-in-linux-server/23261303#23261303)

Comment: oh no when i start it myself everything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to start it "from nodejs", you can start mongodb when you start your node.js server using the child_process module.

Add the code below in your app code :

```
var child_process = require('child_process')
child_process.exec('start mongod', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why `     Uncaught Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c  mongod`